# method works n times before playing card game, fails first time afterwards

Tags: ios, xcode6, didselectrowatindexpath

I really don't know how to title this question, so my apologies in advance....

Building a flash card app. The deck of cards can be filtered through preferences to include/exclude certain continents. I set the filter to include only one continent, then I play the game successfully. After finishing my deck, I decide to include a second continent. Fail.

I'm using a TableViewController to display the six continents. Prototype cell is "Right detail". `textLabel.text` is Continent name. `detailText.text` shows inclusion/exclusion state.

All continents start as "include". Click on a row, it toggles on/off.

I can make changes on the screen, save the settings, come back and make more changes without crashing. App *only* crashes after going through the deck one time, be it 10 cards or 100.

Error Message: `-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *name = cell.textLabel.text;
if ([[GameSettingsObject sharedInstance].chosenContinents containsObject:name]) {
    if ([[GameSettingsObject sharedInstance].chosenContinents count]>1) {
        [[GameSettingsObject sharedInstance].chosenContinents removeObject:name];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"exclude";
    }
} else {
    [[GameSettingsObject sharedInstance].chosenContinents addObject:name];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"include";
}
```

}

Any ideas?

Comment: (forehead slap!) Yes, that's it! I found the place where I saved the settings by making a `copy` and not a `mutableCopy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add objects only into mutable array. So I think that your array becomes to NSArray somehow. Check that.